# seperate the cuda host code in .cpp file

Tags: visual-c++, cuda

**main.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include "cuda.h"


using namespace std;
void cuda_calculation();


int main()
{
    cuda_calculation();
    return 0;
}
```

**cu.h**

```
void call(int , int ,float*  , int  );
```

**cuda.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include "cu.h"




void cuda_calculation()
{
  float *a_h, *a_d;  // Pointer to host & device arrays
  const int N = 10;  // Number of elements in arrays
  size_t size = N * sizeof(float);
  a_h = (float *)malloc(size);        // Allocate array on host
  cudaMalloc((void **) &a_d, size);   // Allocate array on device
  // Initialize host array and copy it to CUDA device
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) a_h[i] = (float)i;
  cudaMemcpy(a_d, a_h, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  // Do calculation on device:
  int block_size = 4;
  int n_blocks = N/block_size + (N%block_size == 0 ? 0:1);
  void call(n_blocks, block_size,&a_d, N);
  /*square_array <<< n_blocks, block_size >>> (a_d, N);*/
  // Retrieve result from device and store it in host array
  cudaMemcpy(a_h, a_d, sizeof(float)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  // Print results
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) printf("%d %f\n", i, a_h[i]);
  // Cleanup
  free(a_h); cudaFree(a_d);
}
```

**cu.cu**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cu.h"
#include <cuda.h>

// Kernel that executes on the CUDA device
__global__ void square_array(float *a, int N)
{
  int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  if (idx<N) a[idx] = a[idx] * a[idx];
}


//}


void call(int a,int b,float* c,int d)
{
square_array <<< 3,4 >>> (c,d);
}
```

I tried to seperate the kernal code and host code in a cpp file, however the following error prevails:

```
Error    'cudaMemcpy': identifier not found and the other cuda related identifier is not identified.

how to use the cuda related identifier in cpp file and call the kernal functions
```

Comment: have you correctly set the build customizations?

Comment: yes, I had and now I have solved it as the answer is provided below

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors: `void cuda_calculation();` needs to be visible to main.cpp through a header file (cu.h).

Also **make sure to compile your .cu files with nvcc** and NOT as a standard C++ file. Use CUDA compilation rules to make this process easy (installed by default as part of CUDA toolkit)

Comment: recently I included #include "cuda.cpp" in the main.cpp file and again the same error prevails

Comment: Make sure to compile your .cu file with nvcc, post the entire command line to help us debug your problem

Comment: I have used the visual studio to run the code and total code is posted above

Comment: There are two kind of files here: regular C++ source host files (which will run on your CPU) and .cu CUDA C++ source device files (which will run on your GPU). You need to compile the first with visual studio as you've always done, the latter with a tool called "nvcc.exe" provided by the NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit. In short you need to access the properties of your .cu files and make sure "CUDA C build" is set if you want to make it easy. Read about nvcc and how to compile CUDA files outside visual studio first

Comment: I have configured cuda 5.0 properly in visual studio and is running the basic code when the code is used in a single .cu file but when i tried to managed it in seperate file, it is giving the error.

Answer (score 0):

after a long trial ,I came with the proper output,

to include the cuda identifier in the cpp files we not only need to include **cuda.h** but also we need to include **cuda_runtime.h** as

**cuda.cpp** as

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include<cuda_runtime.h>

#include "cu.h"
#include "cud.h"





//void call(int , int ,float * , int  );

void cuda_calculation()
{
  float *a_h, *a_d;  // Pointer to host & device arrays
  const int N = 10;  // Number of elements in arrays
  size_t size = N * sizeof(float);
  a_h = (float *)malloc(size);        // Allocate array on host
  cudaMalloc((void **) &a_d, size);   // Allocate array on device
  // Initialize host array and copy it to CUDA device
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) a_h[i] = (float)i;
  cudaMemcpy(a_d, a_h, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  // Do calculation on device:
  int block_size = 4;
  int n_blocks = N/block_size + (N%block_size == 0 ? 0:1);
   call(n_blocks, block_size,a_d, N);
  /*square_array <<< n_blocks, block_size >>> (a_d, N);*/
  // Retrieve result from device and store it in host array
  cudaMemcpy(a_h, a_d, sizeof(float)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  // Print results
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) printf("%d %f\n", i, a_h[i]);
  // Cleanup
  free(a_h); 
  cudaFree(a_d);
}
```

so the others files are

**main.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include "cud.h"


using namespace std;



int main()
{
    cuda_calculation();
    return 0;
}
```

**cud.h**

```
void cuda_calculation();
```

**cu.h**

```
void call(int , int ,float*  , int  );
```

**cu.cu**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cu.h"
#include <cuda.h>

// Kernel that executes on the CUDA device
__global__ void square_array(float *a, int N)
{
  int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  if (idx<N) a[idx] = a[idx] * a[idx];
}


//}


void call(int a,int b,float* c,int d)
{
square_array <<< 3,4 >>> (c,d);
}
```